# Using JAXB to read/write on xml files with several version of XSD?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

The goal of the project is to read/write from an xml file (with xsd schema) and support minor changes in the XSD Schema.

Any one have an idea how to make my code support several version of an XSD ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you intend to generate Java classes from the XML schemas, you'll have different sets of classes, resulting in (more or less) different programs. This is merely a configuration management issue (unless you didn't ask the right question).

Comment: I am thinking about generate java classes from the xml schemas and provide a Jar. This jar will be automatically added to the lib of the program and then it will be parsed and filled using java reflection. What do you think ? The customer want to avoid any modification in the code after each update in the schema (it is a standalone application)

Comment: If the XSD is changed it'll mean that the program will have to process a different XML. How can the customer expect a program to do that without being changed? - If the program should merely ignore additional XML elements, that's a different matter.